# tmux session getting killed when I have a broken pipe from ssh

Tags: python-3.6, paramiko, tmux

I am using paramiko as ssh client for remote machine and starting a new tmux session using the client. After sometime I am getting a broken pipe exception. `Socket exception: Connection reset by peer (54)`. Because of this my tmux sessions are killed. I tried changing ssh.socket to service and also added Killmode in ssh@.service. But still i am getting the same exception. Any suggestions to solve this error?

Comment: Check for socket timeouts and network issues. Are the tmux screens changing at all? If not there might not be any data being sent. Are other sockets being broken as well?

Comment: Are you sure the sessions were killed, or that you were just detached? One of the primary use cases of `tmux` is to guard against this type of disconnection.